# Why is elliptic curve parameter $a=-3$ somehow special

Tags: elliptic-curves

Considering the equation of the elliptic curves over $GF(p)$

$y^3 = x^2+ax+b$ ,

why is there some magic in using $a=-3$ ? In some well known curves (e.g. P-256) only $b$ is specified, while $a$ ist taken as $-3$. In a software library I use, $-3$ is the default value, what means, that is assumes $a=-3$ if not otherwise specified.

Why is $a=-3$ special?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that choosing $a=-3$ allows for a more efficient computation of the doubling operation, when used in projective coordinates.

In fact if you look at the doubling formula in, for example, Jacobian coordinates from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Jacobian_Coordinates#Point_Doubling_.284M_.2B_6S_or_4M_.2B_4S.29) you can see that it requires the computation of an intermediate value as $M = 3*X^2 + a*Z^4$, where $(X,Y,Z)$ is the Jacobian representation of the affine point $(x,y)$ through the relation $(x,y) = (X/Z^2,Y/Z^3)$.

That formula to compute $M$ can be simplified to $M = 3*(X + Z^2)*(X - Z^2)$ exchanging the computation of two squares $X^2$ and $(Z^2)^2$ with the multiplication $(X + Z^2)*(X - Z^2)$ and, of course, you also avoided the multiplication by $a$.

This results in a more efficient computation of the doubling formula and works well even in [homegeneous](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Standard_Projective_Coordinates) or [Chudnovsky](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cryptography/Prime_Curve/Chudnovsky_Coordinates) coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

One of the requirement of an elliptic curves is its absence of singular point.

Given her Weierstrass Form $$y^2 = x^3 + a x + b$$
The discriminant must not be nul: $$4a^3 + 27b^2 \neq0$$
if $a= -3$ then this becomes:$$4\times (-27) + 27 b^2 \neq 0\\-4+b^2\neq0
\\b\neq2\ \land\ b \neq -2$$
This is rather simple to check when choosing $b$.

> Yet another advantage of the NIST curves is that they use a = −3, which improves addition in Jacobian coordinates.

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) (also cf Ruggero's answer).